# Easier way to add input field text to textarea?

Tags: jquery

This is a bit complicated to explain. I have a few input fields which I want to add into a textarea field. If an input field is filled out, it should automatically add a header. This is how I want it to output (from the input fields):

```
HEADER
Input field 1
Input field 2

HEADER 2
Input field 3
Input field 4

HEADER 3
Input field 5
Input field 6
```

If the input fields are empty, the textarea should be empty. If you fill out input field 1, it should automatically add "HEADER" before it. Currently, each "section" has two input fields with the same classes. In this case, there are 3 sections with 3 classes. To add the first two, this is how I do it:

```
var texts = [];
if($(".header:first").val()) {
    $('.header').each(function () {
        if($(this).val()) {
            texts.push($(this).val());
        }
    });
}
```

The class "header" is the first two input fields. Is there an easy way to do this? If possible, I want all input fields to have the same class, but I feel like I am repeating myself with this. Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: More needs to be known about the layout to do this effectively. Suggest you put a demo together in jsfiddle.net with basic structure for `rows`

Comment: Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kc6q8rL2/1/ - look how the jQuery is basically copy-pasted. Is there an easier way?

Comment: don't understand what you mean ... easier to do what? What is expected behavior of these headers? Seems to work already. Nothing in the question mentioned the headers being in a  textarea

Comment: It works fine. Problem is that if I want 10 of these input fields, I need to copy-paste this 5 times. The things I have to copy-paste have basically the same information in it, so I want to create something like a function to make it less code.

Comment: sure use `clone()`. to be honest that intention was not made clear at all in question. It actually sounded like you needed help creating the headers. Would help to get a bit more organized when posting qquestions

Answer (score 0):

Try to listen to the `change` `event` of all inputs.

```
$(".input-class").on("change", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var header = "<h1>Header N</h1>";
    if($this.val())
       $(header).insertBefore($this);

})
```

Comment: How does this add a header before each section?

Comment: Edited, maybe now it's better.

Comment: Where do I set header 2? And header 3? And sections? This is how I have it now, which is pretty much a copy-paste: http://puu.sh/dH7vi.png

Comment: @Snorlax it is scalable; the event is bound to every input, so every one can set its header. 
Anyway I feel like not getting at all the behaviour.

Comment: This is what I want to achieve: http://puu.sh/dH7RV.png but the code I showed you is copy-paste, and then edit a few names. Surely that can be achieved better?